# ElasticSearch .net GeoDistance filter not working

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch.net

The query I created Kibana Dev tools works 100% and returns results within the 10 km distance range. It is structured like this:

```
GET /catdb/_search
{
"query": {
    "bool" : {
        "must" : {
         "match_phrase": {
  "NAME": {
    "query": "cats",
        "slop": 3

  }
    }
        },
        "filter" : {
            "geo_distance" : {
                "distance" : "10km",
         "location":{
           "lat" : -25.859919,
            "lon" : 28.183966
                    }
            }
        }
    }
  }
 }
```

The query I created in c# using NEST is structured the same but returning results from far outside the geo Distance

```
        var catsSearch = client.Search<dynamic>(s => s.From(0).Size(20).Query(
            q => q.Bool(
            b => b.Must(
                m => m.MatchPhrase(
                    n => n.Field("NAME").Query("cats").Slop(slop))).Filter(
                     f => f.GeoDistance(
                      g => g.Distance(10, DistanceUnit.Kilometers).Location(-25.859919, 28.183966))))));
```

I also tried passing a GeoLocation Object in the location filter.
Any advice to what I might be doing wrong or how to debug this will be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look to see what the client is sending to Elasticsearch: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/troubleshooting.html

Comment: From a cursory glance, the index and type are not specified: the index may be using the default index configured on `ConnectionSettings`, and the type will be inferred from `T` on `Search<T>(...)`. If you wanted to search all types in the index `catdb`, then you can specify `AllTypes()` on the request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didnot specify the field of Geodistance: .Field(p=>p.Location)

Comment: How would I specify a Field in this case? Since Im using dynamic

Comment: field("fieldname") NEST isnot able to guess the location fieldbyhim self. A work around if you have to work with a "generic" querry could be to parse your mapping first to get the localtion fieldname and set this name in your querry.

Comment: I tried adding n.Field("location") but that doesn't work, Also I can't parse it because they want to dynamically add and remove other fields

Comment: If you dont know they location fieldName, Nest wont work. So you have to add a function (and set a dictionnary type - fieldname i  thinck to avoid search it each querry) to parse your type mappings to find it (Client.GetMappings<dynamic>).

Comment: looking at Kibana Dev request, just need to add `.Field("location")` to `g => g` lambda passed to `GeoDistance`